# Why SBT creates "default" directory when i use publishLocal command?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to publish my local library into .ivy2 directory. Using `sbt puslishLocal` command everything works fine, but it creates a path named *default*, followed by other path that contains the name of project.

What is that *default* path? How to remove it?

I'm using sbt 1.2.8 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem :)

That path was created because I don't set `organization` property in my build.sbt file.